# What is causing SWT Invalid thread access error when trying to test SWT application?

Tags: java, macos, maven, junit, swt

I have been trying to test my SWT application. I have the `AppViewImplTest` JUnit class written below. The tests are passing without any errors or failures in Eclipse but when running mvn clean install from the command line, they are showing as an SWT Invalid thread access error. It also mentions "***WARNING: Display must be created on main thread due to Cocoa restrictions." I'm sure I'm just missing something, but wonder if someone could point it out that has more experience with this? This happens at the point where I am calling `getShell()` in `setUp()`. I would love to hear some insight. I've seen examples of this working before and I've searched for answers from other questions but nothing on testing. Thanks in advance.

```
public class AppViewImplTest {
    private Shell shell;
    private Display display;
    private AppViewImpl testAppViewImpl;

    /**
     * Runs before the tests to get a new Shell.
     */
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        shell = getShell();
    }

    /**
     * Test to ensure that {@link IllegalArgumentException} is thrown when the
     * parent shell is null.
     */
    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testErrorWhenAppViewShellIsNull() {
        new AppViewImpl(null);
    }

    /**
     * Test to ensure that the minimum size is set with constructor.
     */
    @Test
    public void testShellMinimumSizeIsSet() {
        testAppViewImpl = new AppViewImpl(shell);
        assertEquals(shell.getSize(), shell.getMinimumSize());
    }

    private Shell getShell() {
        if (shell != null && shell.isDisposed()) {
            shell = null;
        }
        Display currentDisplay = (this.display != null) ? this.display : Display.getCurrent();
        if (currentDisplay != null && !currentDisplay.isDisposed()) {
            Shell active = currentDisplay.getActiveShell();
            if (active != null) {
                shell = new Shell(active);
            }
        }
        if (shell == null) {
            shell = new Shell(currentDisplay);
        }
        return shell;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not a JUnit or Maven expert, but 'Invalid thread access' means the code is trying to access SWT code from a thread which is not the main UI thread. 'Display must be created on main thread' is specific to macOS and means the UI thread must be the first thread started - usually the JVM argument -XstartOnFirstThread is used for that.

Comment: "WARNING: Display must be created on main thread due to Cocoa restrictions." probably indicates that the JVM running the tests was launched without `-XstartOnFirstThread`.